# How can I get a list of processes running by a specific user?

Tags: c++, linux, proc

I'm reading the list of running processes from /proc/. And from the file (status) I get some information I need about the process.
I need to know the user ID that started the process. In the status file I see two fields that are interesting to me: uid and gid. After reading on the Internet, I found out that uid is the user identifier, and gid is the group identifier.
please tell me how to read the value into the `uid_t` type? So I can compare it with the value obtained from the `geteuid()` function?
I need to select from the list of processes only processes launched by a specific user.

This is how I currently read information from the /proc/status file:

```
ProcessInfo getInfoFromFileByPID(char pid[], const char* filename)
{
   printf("getInfoFromFileByPID param = %s %s\n", pid, filename);
 
   char            path[256];
   FILE*           fp;
   char            szFullLine[256];
   size_t          len;
   ProcessInfo     process;
   uid_t uid       = geteuid();  // получим идентификатор текущего пользователя
 
 
   snprintf(path, sizeof(path), filename, pid);
 
   fp = fopen(path, "r");
   if (fp)
   {
       memset(szFullLine, 0x00, sizeof(szFullLine));
       len = fread(szFullLine, sizeof(char), sizeof(szFullLine), fp);
       fclose(fp);
 
 
       if( len > 0 )
       {
 
           std::string str(szFullLine);
           std::map<std::string, std::string> map = mappify(str);
 
 
           if (map.find("Name") != map.end())
               process.Name = map["Name"];
           if (map.find("Pid") != map.end())
               process.PID = std::stoi(map["Pid"]);
 
 
           std::cout << "info: " << str << std::endl;
           return process;
       }
   }
   return process;
}
```

Please tell me where I can find out what IP addresses and ports the process uses? For example, if I launched Skype, I want to get the hostname where it sends data and the port.

Comment: There is existing software like `ps`, `top`, `htop`, `lsof`, `netstat`, `strace`, `wireshark` and probably others you could simply study. That said, you don't send data to a hostname but to a network address (IPv4 or IPv6 usually), so it's impossible to answer your question. BTW: There are quite a few issues with your code that could be improved. Once you have a bit of working code, consider submitting it for review at codereview.stackexchange.com. Make sure to read their site guidelines first though.

Comment: thank you for your advice.
Is the software you describe open source so I can study it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Uid:` field in `/proc/PID/status` is indeed what you want. Linux however has not just one UID that is assigned to a process, but 4:

- The real user id
- The effective user id
- The saved set user id
- The filesystem access user id

This is also the order in which the numbers in `/proc/PID/status`

Unless you are doing something weird when it comes to permissions, what you *most likely* want to use is either the real user id (first field) or the effective user id (second field). (`getuid()` returns the real user id, `geteuid()` returns the effective user id.)

So on a desktop Linux system, you'll most likely have a line in the form

```
Uid:    1000      1000      1000      1000
```

If you split that string and take the first number, that'll be your real user id, the second number the effective user id. For example, when you run `sudo -i`, that'll have the following user ids:

```
Uid:    1000      0       0       0
```

The real user id `1000` indicates that the user with id `1000` started the program, but the other ids being set to `0` indicate that the program actually has root privileges. (Root is always uid `0`.)

As to the other part of your question: `uid_t` is just an integer type, typically `unsigned int` on modern Linux systems, which is a 32bit unsigned integer.

Answer (score 0):

The `uid_t` in kernel is `unsigned int`, you can just do some type conversion thing to compare the data.
You can use `netstat` to get the relevant data of some network thing.